# Find indexes of unquoted words in a string using `re.finditer()` method

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I'm trying to find the position (index) of unquoted words in a string, but all my tests have been unsuccessful.

For the string: `string='foo "bar" baz'` I'd like to get

```
(0, 3)   # This for foo
(10, 13) # This for baz
# I'd like to skip the quoted "bar"
```

However, every regular expression I try includes the quoted `'bar'` or parts of it:

```
string='foo "bar" baz'
_RE_UNQUOTED_VALUES = re.compile(r"([^\"']\w+[^\"'])")
print([m.span() for m in _RE_UNQUOTED_VALUES.finditer(string)])
```

outputs: `[(0, 4), (5, 8), (9, 13)]`

Or using:

```
_RE_UNQUOTED_VALUES = re.compile(r"(?!(\"|'))\w+(?!(\"|'))")
# Outputs [(0, 3), (5, 7), (10, 13)]
```

Is this not doable with regular expressions? Am I misunderstanding how [`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
string="foo 'bar' baz"
ms = re.finditer(r"""\b(?<!['"])\w+\b(?!['"])""", string)
print([(x.start(), x.end()) for x in ms])
# => [(0, 3), (10, 13)]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/saPm6A).

The `\b(?<!['"])\w+\b(?!['"])` regex matches a word boundary first, then the `(?<!')` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a `'`/`"` char immediately on the left, then matches one or more word chars, checks the word boundary position again and the `(?!['"])` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a `'`/`"` char immediately on the right.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClDNew/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```py
import re

string='foo "bar" baz'
_RE_UNQUOTED_VALUES = re.compile(r"(?<!['\"\w])\w+(?![\"'\w])")
print([m.span() for m in _RE_UNQUOTED_VALUES.finditer(string)])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3), (10, 13)]
```

In this case using `\w` as well as the quote characters in the negative lookarounds forces the engine to match only whole words that are not surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it with `.index` instead of a regex? This way it's much more readable and extensible. For example:

```
strstr=lambda s, sub: (s.index(sub), s.index(sub)+len(sub))
strstr('foo "bar" baz', 'foo')
# (0, 3)
strstr('foo "bar" baz', 'baz')
# (10, 13)
```

However, if you don't know the input and need to use regex, @Wiktor's answer is better.